# Is there a traffic-light colormap for matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colormap

I love matplotlibs colormaps. They are nice and easy way to improve graphic illustratations. [Matplotlib provides this overview to all default colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#list-colormaps). But is there a colormap resembling a traffic light scheme? If not, how do I customize a colormap to span from green to yellow to red?

Comment: Since red and green are hard to distinguish by the colorblind, these are not usually used together in this way.

Comment: Though I see your point, there green/yellow/red are used quite often nontheless. In this particular case, I am trying to plot red-light-waiting times for a city and its traffic. It just seemed fitting...

Comment: `cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["green","yellow","red"])`